# What causes "Zed" time?

Tags: killing-floor

In *Killing Floor*, sometimes the game enters slow-motion. This is called "Zed Time". Zed Time allows for more time to aim, and allows for more accurate headshots.

What causes Zed Time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming you mean Zed Time.

[Zed Time](http://www.kf-wiki.com/wiki/Help:Glossary#Zed_time) is an apparently random event triggered by getting "cool shots." These have been reported as long-range headshots, messy bomb kills, etc.

[Source](http://forums.tripwireinteractive.com/showpost.php?p=430137&postcount=2)

Comment: Some perks get more Zed Time than others, i.e. berserkers and commandos, IIRC.  Sharpshooters and medics hardly get any - you have to pull off some extreme range headshots or very fast series of headshot kills to get it.